# Edit names and create a directory with the edited name bash

Tags: bash

I have a file with many names, such as:

```
ABC_DEF.ghi
GHI_JKL.ghi
```

I want to get only the first part of the name and create a directory with that name, that is:

```
ABC_DEF
GHI_JKL
```

I wrote the following command which edits the name but I can't figure out how to create a directory with the changed name, that is I don't know how to use the output of the previous command as the input of the next:

```
while read name; do echo $name | cut -d . -f1 <; done < file.text
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while read -r name; do echo mkdir "${name%.*}"; done < file.text
```

If everything looks okay, remove `echo`.

Take a look at `man bash` section Parameter Expansion.

Answer (score 0):

this way should work:

```
sed -r 's/(.+)\.ghi$/mkdir "\1"/' file|sh
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation, also?